# Best way to replace item in object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I will fetch this data, the data is always diffrent. Sometimes admin exist sometimes not.

What is the best way to remove all the values in admin and add new value, if admin key exist?

```
  const apiFetched = [{
      persons: {
          firstName: "John",
          lastName: "Doe",
      },
      admin: {
          firstName: "Jeff",
          lastName: "Pan",
      }
    }]
```

**If admin key exist** I would like to **replace everything in admin and add these**:

`{ firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Jack" }`

like this:

```
const apiFetched = [{
  persons: {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
  },
  admin: {
    firstName: "Alan",
    lastName: "Jack",
  },
}];
```

Comment: What code have you written before posting here in an attempt to satisfy the requirements you describe? We won’t write your code for you, see [ask].

Comment: What research have you done? The two topics at hand here (checking if a key exists in an object; deleting/replacing the contents of an object key value) have been asked and answered at length on this very site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- iterate the array via [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- for each item which features an [own `admin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) ...

  - [`assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to this item's `admin` property/object another object like `superUser` which can feature equally named and/or additional properties ...

    - in the 1st case, *key-value* pairs will be replaced/overwritten,
    - in the 2nd case the `admin` object would aggregate/accumulate new *entries*.

```js
const apiFetched = [{
  persons: {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
  },
  admin: {
    firstName: "Jeff",
    lastName: "Pan",
  },
}];

const superUser = { firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Jack" };

apiFetched
  .forEach(item => {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('admin')) {

      Object.assign(item.admin, superUser);
    }
  });

console.log({ apiFetched });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
const apiFetched = [{
  persons: {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
  },
  admin: {
    firstName: "Jeff",
    lastName: "Pan",
  }
}]

apiFetched.forEach(i => {
  if (i.admin) {
    i.admin = {
      firstname: "Alan",
      lastname: "Jack"
    }
  }
})

console.log(apiFetched)
```